# PyQt5 Custom Widget Opens in Another Window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I started out with PyQt5 recently. I wanted to create a custom widget and then insert it into the main window of an application.

The custom Widget:

```py
class ScoreCard(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScoreCard, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
        self.pressing = False
        self.init_ui()
        self.show()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Layout in here
```

And this is the main Application:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from scorecard import ScoreCard
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()
        self.show()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setGeometry(300,300,800,700)
        window_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        recent_playcard = ScoreCard()
        window_layout.addWidget(recent_playcard)
        self.setLayout(window_layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    execute = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Why is it that whenever I run the main Application, the custom widget appears in another window? I even tried removing the frame and setting the parent to none, but none of that changed this behavior. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I mixed up `QMainWindow` and `QDialog` I should be using a central widget for the main application instead of setting a layout..

Comment: You're also calling self.show() in the __init__ method of the ScoreCard class, which is unnecessary, as well as setting window hints on a widget that will be in a layout, rather than one that will be displayed as a separate window.

Worth mentioning that if you set the parent of a widget to None, that will actually trigger the exact behaviour you see; it will detach the widget in question and parent it to a new window, if a class instance hasn't garbage collected it. In most cases, widgets with their parents set to None will simply be destroyed if nothing is keeping a reference to them.